# MySQL: GROUP BY with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm need to get similar ads from the base without repeating... This code will give the same ads but with different images of it...

```
"SELECT DISTINCT a.*, ct.cityname as cityname, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.timestamp) AS timestamp, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.createdon) AS createdon, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.expireson) AS expireson,p.picfile as picfile,cat.catid,cat.catname as catname,scat.subcatname as subcatname, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(feat.featuredtill) AS featuredtill $xfieldsql
            FROM $t_ads a   
                INNER JOIN $t_subcats scat ON scat.subcatid = a.subcatid
                INNER JOIN $t_cats cat ON scat.catid = cat.catid
                    INNER JOIN $t_cities ct ON a.cityid = ct.cityid
                LEFT OUTER JOIN $t_adpics p ON a.adid = p.adid AND p.isevent = '0'
                LEFT OUTER JOIN $t_adxfields axf ON a.adid = axf.adid
                LEFT OUTER JOIN $t_featured feat ON a.adid = feat.adid AND feat.adtype = 'A'
            WHERE a.subcatid = $subcatid 
                AND a.cityid = $cityid 
                AND $visibility_condn_admin 
                AND a.adid != ".$_GET['adid']." 
                ".$similar_jobs_where."
                ".$similar_jobs_order."
                LIMIT ".constant("SIMILAR_JOBS_LIMIT");
```

I think, i must write a GROUP BY somewhere, but where?

FETCH_ARRAY:

```
Array ( [adid] => 7965 [adtitle] => Iphone 3gs 32gb [addesc] => Text. [area] => м.Улица академика янгеля [cityname] => Москва [timestamp] => 1327927914 [createdon] => 1327875932 [7] => 1359411932 [expireson] => 1359411932 [8] => 4f25b94c483c75f062cd1d573.jpg [picfile] => 4f25b94c483c75f062cd1d573.jpg [9] => 1 [catid] => 1 [10] => Сотовая связь [catname] => Сотовая связь [11] => Мобильные телефоны [subcatname] => Мобильные телефоны )

Array ( [adid] => 7965 [adtitle] => Iphone 3gs 32gb [addesc] => Text. [area] => м.Улица академика янгеля [cityname] => Москва [timestamp] => 1327927914 [createdon] => 1327875932 [7] => 1359411932 [expireson] => 1359411932 [8] => 4f25b94cddab6daa6806c5a56.jpg [picfile] => 4f25b94cddab6daa6806c5a56.jpg [9] => 1 [catid] => 1 [10] => Сотовая связь [catname] => Сотовая связь [11] => Мобильные телефоны [subcatname] => Мобильные телефоны)
```

DIFFERENCE IN IN THE PICFILE

Comment: Can you give an example of a result you're getting and an example of what you want to get?

Comment: @Vache i've added the picture of what's now. so it must be only one ad with the any picture.

Comment: Group By shell stand before the LIMIT expression

Comment: Hey BlueBerry, I think by an example @Vache was refering to an example of the result query you're expecting to get (a table with columns)

Comment: @helle but `GROUP BY a.adid` doesn't work.

Comment: id is too specific I think. Group by name

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN $t_adpics p ON a.adid = p.adid AND p.isevent = '0'... Is there a join criteria missing here which would cause the 2nd picture to be ignored? (What are the keys on T_ads and t_adpics?)  if no key is missing then maybe you just want to get the max/min pic and be done?)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should GROUP BY the Product Name.
However, I don't know if you get the desired image then. there for I would need more Information about your table-structures.

Answer (score 0):

Group by won't help you if the distinct didn't help you.  Without understanding why you're getting two records, you will not be able to solve this problem.  So the question becomes: what is making these two records NOT distinct?

The problem is likely that the timestamps for these two records are different; thus you get two instead of one. Return only those values you NEED to display the Ad instead of a.* and all these time stamps.

Alternatively, you could be getting multiple records because you have multiple in any of the joined tables causing a second instance of that Ad to appear due to the fact that you have a one to many somewhere that you were not expecting.

Distinct will typically remove such things (or group by) but ONLY if the criteria making the many in the one-to-many-relationship is excluded from the select statement.

So run the SQL you posted directly against the DB and see what is making the record not-unique and then ask do you need to return that column?  If not, then excluding it will solve your problem.